# Perl DBI/PostgreSQL min function

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

I'm using Perl DBI/PostgreSQL, and I want to retrieve a minimum value in a column but I get a 'Use of uninitialized value $id in concatenation (.) or string' message for the following code:

```
my $id = 0;
$sth = $dbh->prepare("
    select min(col_id)
    from table
    where col_num = x
") or die $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute() or die $dbh->errstr;
while (my $results = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    $id = $results->{col_id};
}
print "$id";
```

It works in the postgresql editor, but not in perl. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no `col_id` column in your result set. You're computing `min(col_id)` so `$results` will have a `min` key, not a `col_id` key. You want to say:

```
$id = $results->{min};
```

to extract the value you're looking for. Or you could add an alias in your SELECT:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("
    select min(col_id) as min_col_id
    from table
    where col_num = x
") or die $dbh->errstr;
```

and use that name when looking at `$results`:

```
$id = $results->{min_col_id};
```